# have R halt the EC2 machine it's running on

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have a few work flows where I would like R to halt the Linux machine it's running on after completion of a script. I can think of two similar ways to do this:

1. run R as root and then call `system("halt")`
2. run R from a root shell script (could run the R script as any user) then have the shell script run `halt` after the R bit completes.

Are there other easy ways of doing this?

The use case here is for scripts running on AWS where I would like the instance to stop after script completion so that I don't get charged for machine time post job run. My instance I use for data analysis is an EBS backed instance so I don't want to terminate it, simply suspend. Issuing a halt command from inside the instance is the same effect as a stop/suspend from AWS console.

Comment: How bizarre!  I can send you some of my code and if you can figure out how to make it *stop* halting a machine, I'll be very happy.  :)

Comment: Can you clarify several things: (1) Are you using an EBS or S3 backed instance?  (If using EBS, do you intend to terminate or stop the instance?)  (2) How is R being used?  Interactively, via a script, via one of these Hadoop packages, via instance "user data", or some other means?

Comment: Great extension of `sudo make sandwich` which even cleans up the kitchen.  Nice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm impressed that works.  (For anyone else surprised that an instance can stop itself, see notes 1 & 2.)

You can also try "sudo halt", as you wouldn't need to run as a root user, as long as the user account running R is capable of running sudo.  This is pretty common on a lot of AMIs on EC2.

Be careful about what constitutes an assumption of R quitting - believe it or not, one can crash R.  It may be better to have a separate script that watches the R pid and, once that PID is no longer active, terminates the instance.  Doing this command inside of R means that if R crashes, it never reaches the call to halt.  If you call it from within another script, that can be dangerous, too.  If you know Linux well, what you're looking for is the PID from starting R, which you can pass to another script that checks `ps`, say every 1 second, and then terminates the instance once the PID is no longer running.

I think a better solution is to use the EC2 API tools (see: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ for documentation) to terminate *OR* stop instances.  There's a difference between the two of these, and it matters if your instance is EBS backed or S3 backed.  You needn't run as root in order to terminate the instance - the fact that you have the private key and certificate shows Amazon that you're the BOSS, way above the hoi polloi who merely have root access on your instance.

Because these credentials can be used for mischief, be careful about running API tools from a given server, you'll need your certificate and private key on the server.  That's a bad idea in the event that you have a security problem.  It would be better to message to a master server and have it shut down the instance.  If you have messaging set up in any way between instances, this can do all the work for you.

---

Note 1: Eric Hammond [reports](http://alestic.com/mt/mt-search.cgi?blog_id=1&tag=ec2-terminate-instance&limit=20) that the `halt` will only suspend an EBS instance, so you still have storage fees.  If you happen to start a lot of such instances, this can clutter things up.  Your original question seems unclear about whether you mean to terminate or stop an instance.  He has other good advice [on this page](http://alestic.com/2010/01/ec2-instance-locking)

Note 2: A [short thread on the EC2 developers forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=28600) gives advice for Linux & Windows users.

Note 3: EBS instances are billed for partial hours, even when restarted. (See [this thread from the developer forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=212384).)  Having an auto-suspend close to the hour mark can be useful, assuming the R process isn't working, in case one might re-task that instance (i.e. to save on not restarting). Other useful tools to consider: `setTimeLimit` and `setSessionTimeLimit`, and various checkpointing tools (I have a Q that [mentions a couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262485/options-for-caching-memoization-hashing-in-r)).  Using an auto-kill is useful if one has potentially badly behaved code.

Note 4: I recently learned of the `shutdown` command in package `fun`.  This is multi-platform.  See [this blog post](http://cos.name/en/topic/7) for commentary, and code is [here](https://github.com/yihui/fun/blob/c0ca795ce81b3949680d007848580b4b6bd38ac0/R/shutdown.R).  Dangerous stuff, but it could be useful if you want to adapt to Windows.  I haven't tried it, though.

---

Update 1. Three more ideas:

- You could use `.Last()` and `runLast = TRUE` for `q()` and `quit()`, which could shut down the instance.
- If using littler or a script that invokes the script via Rscript, the same command line functions could be used.
- My favorite package of today, `tcltk2` has a neat timer mechanism, called `tclTaskSchedule()` that can be used to schedule the execution of an expression.  You could then go crazy with the execution of stuff just before a hourly interval has elapsed.

Comment: nope... halting stops the instance. At least that's the way my instances are configured :)

Comment: keep in mind that I want to "stop" not "terminate" an instance. I'm using and EBS backed instance so I want to only stop it in order to preserve state. If I terminated it, I would lose state.

Comment: `halt` should do the trick, or you can use the `ec2-stop-instances`.  I like what Eric Hammond suggests, via the `at` command.

Answer (score 1):

```
system("echo 'rootpassword' | sudo halt")
```

However, the downside is having your root password in plain text in the script.

Comment: NB: There may not be a root password if the AMI or accounts are not set up with a password. Such is the beauty of having 17 tons of cryptographic keys sitting around and the joy of mastering private keys, certificates, RSA, x.509, and more.

Comment: that's a really good point Iterator. I have my analysis instance set up with passwords, but this might not need be so. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK those ways you mentioned are the only ones. In any case the script will have to run as root to be able to shut down the machine (if you find a way to do it without root that's possibly an exploit). You ask for an easier way but system("halt") is just an additional line at the end of your script.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` is an option -- it allows you to run certain commands without prompting for any password. Just put something like this in `/etc/sudoers`

```
<username> ALL=(ALL) PASSWD: ALL, NOPASSWD: /sbin/halt
```

(of course replacing  with the name of user running R) and `system('sudo halt')` should just work.