# Memoize and vectorize a custom function

Tags: r, vectorization, memoization

I want to know how to vectorize and memoize a custom function in R. It seems
my way of thinking is not aligned with R's way of operation. So, I gladly
welcome any links to good reading material. For example, R inferno is a nice
resource, but it didn't help to figure out memoization in R.

More generally, can you provide a relevant usage example for the `memoise`
or `R.cache` packages?

I haven't been able to find any other discussions on this subject. Searching
for "memoise" or "memoize" on r-bloggers.com returns zero results. Searching
for those keywords at http://r-project.markmail.org/ does not return helpful
discussions. I emailed the mailing list and did not receive a complete
answer.

I am not solely interested in memoizing the GC function, and I am aware of
Bioconductor and the various packages
available there.

Here's my data:

```
seqs <- c("","G","C","CCC","T","","TTCCT","","C","CTC")
```

Some sequences are missing, so they're blank `""`.

I have a function for calculating GC content:

```
> GC <- function(s) {
    if (!is.character(s)) return(NA)
    n <- nchar(s)
    if (n == 0) return(NA)
    m <- gregexpr('[GCSgcs]', s)[[1]]
    if (m[1] < 1) return(0)
    return(100.0 * length(m) / n)
}
```

It works:

```
> GC('')
[1] NA
> GC('G')
[1] 100
> GC('GAG')
[1] 66.66667
> sapply(seqs, GC)
                  G         C       CCC         T               TTCCT           
       NA 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000   0.00000        NA  40.00000        NA 
        C       CTC 
100.00000  66.66667
```

I want to memoize it. Then, I want to vectorize it.

Apparently, I must have the wrong mindset for using the `memoise` or
`R.cache` R packages:

```
> system.time(dummy <- sapply(rep(seqs,100), GC))
   user  system elapsed
  0.044   0.000   0.054
>
> library(memoise)
> GCm1 <- memoise(GC)
> system.time(dummy <- sapply(rep(seqs,100), GCm1))
   user  system elapsed
  0.164   0.000   0.173
>
> library(R.cache)
> GCm2 <- addMemoization(GC)
> system.time(dummy <- sapply(rep(seqs,100), GCm2))
   user  system elapsed
 10.601   0.252  10.926
```

Notice that the memoized functions are several orders of magnitude slower.

I tried the `hash` package, but things seem to be happening behind the
scenes and I don't understand the output. The sequence `C` should have a
value of `100`, not `NULL`.

Note that using `has.key(s, cache)` instead of `exists(s, cache)` results
in the same output. Also, using `cache[s] <<- result` instead of
`cache[[s]] <<- result` results in the same output.

```
> cache <- hash()
> GCc <- function(s) {
    if (!is.character(s) || nchar(s) == 0) {
        return(NA)
    }
    if(exists(s, cache)) {
        return(cache[[s]])
    }
    result <- GC(s)
    cache[[s]] <<- result
    return(result)
}
> sapply(seqs,GCc)
[[1]]
[1] NA

$G
[1] 100

$C
NULL

$CCC
[1] 100

$T
NULL

[[6]]
[1] NA

$TTCCT
[1] 40

[[8]]
[1] NA

$C
NULL

$CTC
[1] 66.66667
```

At least I figured out how to vectorize:

```
> GCv <- Vectorize(GC)
> GCv(seqs)
                  G         C       CCC         T               TTCCT           
       NA 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000   0.00000        NA  40.00000        NA 
        C       CTC 
100.00000  66.66667
```

**Relevant stackoverflow posts:**

- [Options for caching / memoization / hashing in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262485/options-for-caching-memoization-hashing-in-r)

Comment: Any particular reason you're disregarding the fact that `nchar` and `gregexpr` are already vectorized?

Answer (score 2):

While this won't give you memoization across calls, you can use factors to make individual calls a lot faster if there is a fair bit of repetition. Eg using Joshua's GC2 (though I had to remove fixed=T to get it to work):

```
GC2 <- function(s) {
  if(!is.character(s)) stop("'s' must be character")
  n <- nchar(s)
  m <- gregexpr('[GCSgcs]', s)
  len <- sapply(m, length)
  neg <- sapply(m, "[[", 1)
  len <- len*(neg > 0)
  100.0 * len/n
}
```

One can easily define a wrapper like:

```
GC3 <- function(s) {
  x <- factor(s)
  GC2(levels(x))[x]
}

system.time(GC2(rep(seqs, 50000)))
# user  system elapsed 
# 8.97    0.00    8.99 
system.time(GC3(rep(seqs, 50000)))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.06    0.00    0.06
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you! Memoization will save me a relatively small amount of time from here.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't explicitly answer your question, but this function is ~4 times faster than yours.

```
GC2 <- function(s) {
  if(!is.character(s)) stop("'s' must be character")
  n <- nchar(s)
  m <- gregexpr('[GCSgcs]', s)
  len <- sapply(m, length)
  neg <- sapply(m, "[[", 1)
  len <- len*(neg > 0)
  len/n
}
```

Comment: On my system (x86_64 linux-gnu R 2.15.0), your function is ~3 times slower. I'm testing the speed like this: `system.time(sapply(rep(seqs, 1000), GC))` gets 0.418 elapsed seconds. `system.time(sapply(rep(seqs, 1000), GC2))` gets 1.401 elapsed seconds.

Comment: @KamilSlowikowski That's because you're using the function wrong. Joshua vectorized it, so you should have compared it to `GC2(rep(seqs,1000))`, in which case it is indeed ~4x faster.

Comment: @KamilSlowikowski Although I think he didn't mean to set `fixed = TRUE`.

Comment: Indeed, setting `fixed=T` results in all of the `[[1]]` elements being `-1`. Joshua, thanks for the code! I now know how to take one element out of each item in a list and that `1 * TRUE == 1` and `1 * FALSE == 0`. I feel silly now, realizing that `nchar` and `substr` work on vectors ("lists") of items, especially because the help `?nchar` says so explicitly.

Comment: @joran: thanks for pointing that out. It was part of my testing because `?gregexpr` says using `fixed=TRUE` can be faster... but it shouldn't have made its way into my answer.