# Something like R.cache but in RAM

Tags: r

Just wonder if there exists something like **R.cache** package but working not with hard drive but with RAM instead?

Or maybe there is some hack possible in R, to make **R.cache** package believe that it uses hard drive, but to store it's cache to virtual drive of some kind in RAM?

I've also found this great [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262485/options-for-caching-memoization-hashing-in-r) and tried **memoise** package, but it turned out to be slower then R.cache for my problem, though it works on RAM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you could make a [RAM disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive) and specify that drive as the storage destination for your cache, using `R.cache`.

Comment: +1 -- OP didn't tell us what OS he uses, but that is likely to be the best bet by far.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I tried three different RAM disks programs. Managed to get performance improvement only on one of them. Still it's only 25% improvement, while I expected something more like 80%. Looks like best option for me is to write my own custom cache for the problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You might give [pander](http://rapporter.github.com/pander/)'s `evals` function a try which has a [custom cache](http://rapporter.github.com/pander/#caching) engine.

See the above link for details but in short:

- Enable caching: `evalsOptions('cache', TRUE)` (default value)
- You can set a min. `eval` time in seconds where the results should be cached: `evalsOptions('cache.time', 0.1)` (default value)
- Specify where you want to store the cached values and hashes (`disk` vs. R `environment`): `evalsOptions('cache.mode', 'environment')` (default value)

A short example:

```
> library(pander)

> # first time run
> system.time(evals('sapply(rep(mtcars$hp, 1e3), mean)'))
   user  system elapsed 
 12.269   0.020  12.414 

> # second call
> system.time(evals('sapply(rep(mtcars$hp, 1e3), mean)'))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.003   0.000   0.003 

> # check results any time without recomputing those
> str(evals('sapply(rep(mtcars$hp, 1e3), mean)')[[1]]$result)
 num [1:32000] 110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
> str(evals('sapply(rep(mtcars$hp, 1e3), mean)'))
List of 1
 $ :List of 6
  ..$ src   : chr "sapply(rep(mtcars$hp, 1000), mean)"
  ..$ result: num [1:32000] 110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
  ..$ output: chr [1:1778] "    [1] 110 110  93 110 175 105 245  62  95 123 123 180 180 180 205 215 230  66" "   [19]  52  65  97 150 150 245 175  66  91 113 264 175 335 109 110 110  93 110" "   [37] 175 105 245  62  95 123 123 180 180 180 205 215 230  66  52  65  97 150" "   [55] 150 245 175  66  91 113 264 175 335 109 110 110  93 110 175 105 245  62" ...
  ..$ type  : chr "numeric"
  ..$ msg   :List of 3
  .. ..$ messages: NULL
  .. ..$ warnings: NULL
  .. ..$ errors  : NULL
  ..$ stdout: NULL
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "evals"
```

Comment: Thanks, definitely will try it too.