# Questino about saving workflow in R for complex objects

Tags: r

I am new to using R for data analysis. I have been saving my workflow as an R script file but when I quit R, I run into the problem of needing to re-run all my scripts. This has been a problem since it takes a while (~10 minutes or so) to create some of my objects.

I think I am missing a key aspect of saving work in R. Is there a way to save your work in R such that you can simply go back to continuing your work without needing to re-run all your code?

Thanks!

Comment: you can find pointers to various memoization and caching packages here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262485/options-for-caching-memoization-hashing-in-r)

Comment: Are you saving your `.RData` before you quit?

Comment: If in RStudio, you could look into Projects

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was not saving my .RData before quitting.